# Amplify auth configuration error AWSPinpointProvider - updateEndpoint error TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, configuration, analytics, aws-amplify, aws-pinpoint

**What I want to achieve?**

I want to integrate the aws analytics in my web application that can track user experience. AWS requires you to work with the library **Amplify** to record events in your react web app.

**What I have done so far?**

I have configured the aws amplify cli. I have configured the auth and analytics according to the instructions [here](https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/home?region=us-east-1#/apps/2b30e822004143ad8c6265561bb07eb9/settings/webAnalytics). I have created a pool identity and gave permissions to its unAuth role via privacy policy. I am giving the right Identity pool Id in my code.

**Problem I am facing**

When I configure Analytics or try to record event it keeps giving me the error.

> Credentials - Error loading credentials TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>
> AWSPinpointProvider - set credentials for analytics TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

**Code**

```
import Analytics from '@aws-amplify/analytics';
import Amplify from '@aws-amplify/core';
import Auth from '@aws-amplify/auth';
    Amplify.Logger.LOG_LEVEL = 'DEBUG'
    const amplifyConfig = {
        Auth: {
          identityPoolId: <id>,
          region: 'us-east-1'
        }
      }
      Auth.configure(amplifyConfig);
      
      const analyticsConfig = {
        AWSPinpoint: {
              appId: <app Id>,
              region: 'us-east-1',
              mandatorySignIn: false,
        }
      }
      Analytics.configure(analyticsConfig)
      Analytics.record({ name: 'event-name', attributes: { property1: 'one' } });
```

How can we properly configure analytics and auth to record events via amplify. Any help would be appreciated.